# Editor not supporting scrolling inside the list view for Xamarin.Forms(Android and iOS)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have an Editor control inside ListView. If the text is larger than Editor height, I want to be able to scroll the Editor without clicking inside the Editor. But ListView scroll only working, Editor scroll not working.

```
<ListView 
         x:Name="listProjects" 
         HasUnevenRows="true"
         SeparatorVisibility="None"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Feedbacks}"
         HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
         ItemTapped="Handle_ItemTapped">

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
             <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout  Padding="15,15,15,15" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
               <Editor HeightRequest="50" FontSize="Small"/>
                </StackLayout>
             </ViewCell>
          </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `ScrollView` to wrap the `Editor`like following code.

```
<ScrollView HeightRequest="50">
       <Editor   Text="22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222" ></Editor>
 </ScrollView>
```

Here is running GIF.

[image]

And please update Xamarin forms nuget packages to `4.7.0.1179` or later.

Comment: if above answer is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer(click the “✔” in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue

Comment: Scroll working fine in Editor control. Is it possible to enable editor control, right side scrolling strip?